# C - Keep processes that are still running in list, delete those terminated from list - implement own ps command

Tags: c, linux, linked-list, fork, child-process

I am implementing a way of storing processes in a linked list, from commands I input through stdin. Those that are still running can be kept in the list, the terminated ones must be deleted.

If I want to view the list contents the showProcs function lists all previous ones.  Its kind of implementing own linux ps command.

My code sofar:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

// struct for linked list
typedef struct node {
    pid_t pid;
    char cmd[BUFSIZ];
    struct node *next;
} node_t;

// function for adding command line values and pids
node_t *addme(node_t *head, pid_t pid, char *cmd) {
    node_t *new = (node_t *)malloc(sizeof(node_t));

    if (new == NULL) {
        perror("Error in chainedList");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    new->pid = pid;
    strncpy(new->cmd, cmd, BUFSIZ - 1);
    new->cmd[BUFSIZ - 1] = '\0';
    new->next = head;  // set adress of next to new
    return new;
}

void showProcs(node_t *head) {
    if(head == NULL){
        return;
    }
    printf("%d      |  %s  \n",head->pid,head->cmd);
    showProcs(head->next);
}

void deleteMe(node_t **head, pid_t pid){
    node_t *next_node = NULL;
    while(*head != NULL){
        if((*head)->pid == pid){ // if pid found in list
            if(kill(pid,0) == -1){  // if process isn't running anymore delete it from list
                next_node = (*head)->next;
                free(*head);
            }
        }
        *head = next_node;
    }
}

int main() {
    pid_t pid;
    int argCount = 0;
    char *str1;  // helper string
    const char *mydelim = " \t\n";
    char *myargs[BUFSIZ];  // from stdio.h
    // the command line string
    char input[BUFSIZ];

    // create a linked list
    node_t *chainedList = NULL;

    printf("Welcome\n");
    while (1) {

        printf("$  ");
        fgets(input,BUFSIZ,stdin); // here fgets because scanf does not recognize whitespaces
        input[strcspn(input, "\n")] = '\0';

        // if exit is typed
        if(strstr(input,"exit") != NULL){
            printf("Exiting..\n");
            break;
        }

        switch (pid = fork()) {
            case -1:
                perror("fork error\n");
                break;
            case 0:
                // child process

                // if show is typed
                if(strcmp(input,"show") == 0){
                    printf("PID\t     |   CMD [ ARGS ]\n");
                    showProcs(chainedList);
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    str1 = strtok(input, mydelim);
                    while (str1 != NULL) {
                        myargs[argCount++] = str1;
                        str1 = strtok(NULL, mydelim);
                    }

                    // execute the given command with args and options
                    int execstatus = execv(myargs[0], myargs);
                    // check for execv error
                    if (execstatus < 0) {
                        perror("\nError in execv");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }
                }
                break;
            default:
                wait(NULL); // wait till child proc is finished
                //call addme and store latest node in the list
                chainedList = addme(chainedList, pid, input);
                // delete process if terminated
                // deleteMe(&chainedList, pid);
        }
    }
}
```

the console interaction is somewhat like this (deleteMe commented out):

```
Welcome
$ /usr/bin/echo "dude"
"dude"
$ /usr/bin/date
So 10. Dez 00:16:46 CET 2023
$ show
PID      |   CMD [ ARGS ]
37605      |  /usr/bin/date  
37603      |  /usr/bin/echo "dude"  
$ exit
Exiting..
```

My `deleteMe` function (here commented out) erases the process in the list every time. It detects with `kill(pid,0)` if the process exists and if not, its erased from the list.
**If though, for example, I want to run a script that sleeps for sometime I want to be able to continue inputting commands in the meantime**. If I happen to call showProcs(), **only** the script process should be inside.

Desired output:

```
Welcome
$ /usr/bin/echo "dude"
"dude"
$ /usr/bin/date
So 10. Dez 00:29:22 CET 2023
$./sleeping_script.sh
$ /usr/bin/echo "test"
"test"
$ show
PID      |   CMD [ ARGS ]
69420    |  sleeping_script
$ and so on...
$ exit
Exiting..
```

Should I not make the parent wait? Or implement background processes?
I am kinda stuck on this, any help is appreciated.

Comment: To start, after the `fork`, under the `case 0:`, there are two `break;`. Put `exit(0);` just above each one (e.g.) `exit(0); break;` For clean style, put them on separate lines. This is so the child stops there and doesn't "fall through" and try to execute code meant for the parent.

Comment: The parent shouldn't `wait()` in the `default:` clause if you want to do other things while the child is running.  You should probably capture both the PID and the exit status of the child that is waited for.  When debugging, that's crucial information that should be printed; in the non-debug version, you likely need the PID so you can remove that child from the list of children.  You probably. also need to use `waitpid()` instead of `wait()` so you can specify the `WNOHANG` option.